# RPi 3B+ OpenCV Python3 Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I've been building a smart mirror using a RPi and I wanted Facial Recognition. For that I needed OpenCV for the module i'm using and for the past couple of days I've only had problems with it. I've gotten OpenCV 4.5.0 to install on it but unfortunately it was incompatible with the module as it needs 3.3.0. The Cmake file generates successfully but when I run `sudo make -j4 (or -j1-4)` it throws me a very long python error code at 89% complete. I kept running it a few times switching between make -j1-4 and it managed to get to 100% complete but just kept throwing me the same error and never built. I've tried deleting the OpenCV and Contrib folders and starting fresh but I end up with the same error. I've searched all over for an answer but I can't find anything so this is my last shot.

Cmake build:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules 
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Here is the Error:

```
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/build.make:325: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:21196: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

Here is a PORTION of the log above it that happens right before it throws errors every time, if needed i'll post the entire log of it but it is extremely long:

```
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/opencv/build/modules/python3/pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h:2871:40: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*, _object*)’} to ‘PyCFunction’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
     {"createGrayworldWB", (PyCFunction)pyopencv_cv_xphoto_createGrayworldWB, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "createGrayworldWB() -> retval\n.   @brief Creates an instance of GrayworldWB"},
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:1556:
/home/pi/opencv/build/modules/python3/pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h:2872:44: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*, _object*)’} to ‘PyCFunction’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
     {"createLearningBasedWB", (PyCFunction)pyopencv_cv_xphoto_createLearningBasedWB, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "createLearningBasedWB([, path_to_model]) -> retval\n.   @brief Creates an instance of LearningBasedWB\n.   \n.   @param path_to_model Path to a .yml file with the model. If not specified, the default model is used"},
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:1556:
/home/pi/opencv/build/modules/python3/pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h:2873:37: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*, _object*)’} to ‘PyCFunction’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
     {"createSimpleWB", (PyCFunction)pyopencv_cv_xphoto_createSimpleWB, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "createSimpleWB() -> retval\n.   @brief Creates an instance of SimpleWB"},
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/opencv/build/modules/python3/pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h:2874:35: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*, _object*)’} to ‘PyCFunction’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
     {"dctDenoising", (PyCFunction)pyopencv_cv_xphoto_dctDenoising, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "dctDenoising(src, dst, sigma[, psize]) -> None\n.   @brief The function implements simple dct-based denoising\n.   \n.   <http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/ys-dct/>.\n.   @param src source image\n.   @param dst destination image\n.   @param sigma expected noise standard deviation\n.   @param psize size of block side where dct is computed\n.   \n.   @sa\n.   fastNlMeansDenoising"},
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/opencv/build/modules/python3/pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h:2875:30: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*, _object*)’} to ‘PyCFunction’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
     {"inpaint", (PyCFunction)pyopencv_cv_xphoto_inpaint, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "inpaint(src, mask, dst, algorithmType) -> None\n.   @brief The function implements different single-image inpainting algorithms.\n.   \n.   See the original paper @cite He2012 for details.\n.   \n.   @param src source image, it could be of any type and any number of channels from 1 to 4. In case of\n.   3- and 4-channels images the function expect them in CIELab colorspace or similar one, where first\n.   color component shows intensity, while second and third shows colors. Nonetheless you can try any\n.   colorspaces.\n.   @param mask mask (CV_8UC1), where non-zero pixels indicate valid image area, while zero pixels\n.   indicate area to be inpainted\n.   @param dst destination image\n.   @param algorithmType see xphoto::InpaintTypes"},
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks for taking a look, I really appreciate it.